# Trigonometric identities - without using tanx

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Question: $\csc x = 4 \sec x$ within the range of $0^\circ-360^\circ$. I attempted to do this without using $\tan x$ - challenging myself.

My attempt: 
$$\begin{split}
\dfrac{1}{\sin x}&= \dfrac{4}{\cos x} \\
1&= \dfrac{4 \sin x}{\cos x} \\
\cos x &= 4 \sin x \\
1- \sin x&= 4 \sin x \\
5 \sin x &= 1 \sin x = 1/5 \\
&\arcsin(1/5)
\end{split}
$$
This gave me the wrong answer. Is it because $\cos x = 1-\sin x$ is wrong? Is it only possible if sine and cosine are squared? I hope some one can clear this up. Thank you.

Comment: yes, you can always say $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, but not $\cos x=1-\sin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{split}
&\csc x = \sec x \\
&\dfrac{1}{\sin x} = \dfrac{4}{\cos x} \\
&\cos x -4\sin x = 0 \\
& \sqrt{17}\cos(x+\theta) = 0,\>\>\>\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}\\
\end{split}

Thus,

$$x= \frac\pi2- \sin^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}},\>
 \frac{3\pi}2 - \sin^{-1} \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}},\>$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The problem is that the identity is $\cos^2 x =  1- \sin^2x$. This problem has no 'nice' solution. Observe
$$
\begin{split}
\csc x&= 4\sec x \\
\dfrac{1}{\sin x}&= \dfrac{4}{\cos x} \\
\dfrac{1}{4}&= \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\
\dfrac{1}{4}&= \tan x \\
x&= \tan^{-1}(1/4)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: you meant $\color{red}4\sec x$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, thank you that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Without using tan ...
$$
\csc x = 4 \sec x
\\
\sin x = \frac{\cos x}{4}
\\
16 \sin^2 x = \cos^2 x
\\
16\sin^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x
\\
17 \sin^2 x = 1
\\
\sin x = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}
\\
x = \pm \arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}
$$
Plug in to see that the $+$ is a solution, but the $-$ isn't.